# как сделать обнуление очков после обнуления вопросов

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Нужно сделать обнуление очков после начала нового цикла вопросов.
Сейчас 71 очко, а должно быть 0 после начала нового цикла из 13 вопросов(т.е. вместе с обнулением очков, идет обнуление вопросов, так как их всего тринадцать). Помогите пожалуйста очень хочется узнать как обновлять очки при обновлении цикла вопросов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть код:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let allQuestions = QuestionBank()
    var pickedAnswer :Bool = false
    var questionNumber :Int = 0
    var score :Int = 0
    //Place your instance variables here


    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel !
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel:UILabel !
    @IBOutlet var progressBar: UIView !
    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel:UILabel !

    override func viewDidLoad () {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        nextQuestion()
    }


    @IBAction
    func answerPressed (sender:AnyObject){
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            pickedAnswer = true
        } else if sender.tag == 2 {
            pickedAnswer = false
        }

        checkAnswer()
        questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
        nextQuestion()
    }

    func updateUI () {
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        progressLabel.text = "\(questionNumber + 1) / 13"
        progressBar.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width / 13) * CGFloat(questionNumber + 1)
    }

    func nextQuestion () {
        if questionNumber <= 12 {
            questionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionText
            updateUI()
        } else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Awesome", message:
            "You've finished all the questions, do you want to start over?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Restart", style: .default){
                (UIAlertAction) in
                self.startOver()
            }

            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
        }
    }

    func checkAnswer () {
        let correctAnswer = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].answer

        if correctAnswer == pickedAnswer {
            print("You got it!")
            score = score + 1
        } else {
            print("wrong!")
        }
    }

    func startOver () {
        questionNumber = 0
        nextQuestion()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `startOver()`, после `questionNumber = 0` добавьте `score = 0`